# Why do I get the compiler error "does not name a type" when my code is outside of a function scope?

Tags: c++, c++11, random, compiler-errors, std

I was testing a game engine I am building by generating objects at random positions when I stumbled across this error that I do not understand.

**"foo.h":**

```
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>

namespace foo {

std::default_random_engine r_gen;
auto r_seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();

r_gen.seed(r_seed);  // This is the line giving an error

std::uniform_real_distribution<float> r_dist(-1.0, 1.0);
auto r_float = std::bind(r_dist, r_gen);

}
```

**"main.cpp":**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "foo.h"

int main() {

    // Actually run the program

}
```

Attempting to compile this code gives me the error message:

```
error: 'r_gen' does not name a type
r_gen.seed(r_seed);
^~~~~
```

I am using Eclipse with MinGW. I'm not sure why it is interpreting `r_gen` as a type. And furthermore, wrapping the above code in a function (everything inside namespace `foo`) allows it to compile correctly.

I have a theory question and a pragmatic question:

- **(Theory)** Why does my example code not compile?
- **(Pragmatic)** How should I be arranging this code so that it only seeds the generator once?

Comment: You can't execute a statement like that outside a function.

Comment: @n.m also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375837/why-cant-i-assign-a-value-to-a-variable-in-a-namespace) at least has a similar answer.

Comment: Reopened. Yes, there are lots of answers that say why this doesn’t compile. But none of them shows the simple fix that makes it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the order of the first two definitions, and construct the generator from the seed:

```
auto r_seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
std::default_random_engine r_gen(seed);
```